# error while executing sort and search C functions

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have defined two functions `search` and `sort` which are used in another program. When I try to run the program I get an error `Unexpected Input`. What does the error mean? I don't know what is the problem with my code.

```
#include "helpers.h"

/**
 * Returns true if value is in array of n values, else false.
 */

      bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
      {
        values[n] = n;
        for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
        {
          if(values[n] == value && value > 0)
            return 0;
          else
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
     }

/**
 * Sorts array of n values.
 */


    void sort(int values[], int n)
    {
      int min, swap;
      for(int i=1; i < (n-1); i++)
      {
        min = i;
        for(int j=i+1; j< n; j++)
        {
          if(values[j] < values[min])
              min = j;
        } 
        if(min != i)
        {
          swap = values[i];
          values[i] = values[min];
          values[min] = swap;
        }
      }
      return;
    }
```

This is the main program in which i will call the above two functions

```
       #include <stdio.h>
       #include <stdlib.h>

       #include "helpers.h"

      // maximum amount of hay

       const int MAX = 65536;

      int main(int argc, string argv[])
         {
   // ensure proper usage

            if (argc != 2)
          {
           printf("Usage: ./find needle\n");
           return -1;
           }

     // remember needle

          int needle = atoi(argv[1]);

         // fill haystack
           int size;
           int haystack[MAX];
           for (size = 0; size < MAX; size++)
             {
                // wait for hay until EOF

                 printf("\nhaystack[%d] = ", size);
                  int straw = GetInt();
                    if (straw == INT_MAX)
                    {
                          break;
                     }

                   // add hay to stack

                 haystack[size] = straw;
             }
             printf("\n");

        // sort the haystack

         sort(haystack, size);

     // try to find needle in haystack

          if (search(needle, haystack, size))
            {
             printf("\nFound needle in haystack!\n\n");
             return 0;
            }
            else
           {
               printf("\nDidn't find needle in haystack.\n\n");
               return 1;
           }
        }
```

Comment: can show more code? form where you call `search`,`sort` functions.

Comment: and post exact error you are getting

Comment: sorry, the error is "UNEXPECTED END OF INPUT"

Comment: That sounds like error message printed by your program. Yet the code in question does not show it. So it's hard to say what the problem is. But even if these two functions are possibly buggy, they almost certainly have nothing to do with the error.

Comment: @patelN It's not whole program.It's just shows only function definitions. You need to give exact errors and which function are you calling?

Comment: @patelN post it in question window not here.

Comment: ok sorry, i just edited the post

Comment: @patelN `int main(int argc, string argv[])` here `string` is not valid type in `c`. Also delete comment.

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't causing the error, it certainly will make one. In your search function, you have an array of size `n` and access index `n`, despite the maximum index being `n-1`.
Also, your loop in search will always exit immediately without actually checking anything. I highly recommend you step through each line of the code and substitute values in for the variables to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Can you Explain what does the parameters of `search()` actually do

```
bool search(int value,int values[],int n)//what is value,what's n.I mean what are they
```

According to your code for loop is

```
for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
      if(values[n] == value && value > 0)
        return 0;//returns 0 if -- if condition is true
      else
        return 1;//returns 1 if -- if condition is false
    }
```

`Anyway if -- if condition is true or false return value is sent to calling function. so for loop ends in only one comparison so why do you use for loop???`

Answer (score -1):

change your code to this

```
  bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
  {
    bool flag=false;
    values[n] = n;
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
     if(values[n] == value && value > 0)
     flag=true;


     }
     return flag;
     }
```

for sorting

```
for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
  {

    for(int j=i+1; j< n; j++)
    {
      if(values[j] < values[i])

      swap = values[i];
      values[i] = values[j];
      values[j] = swap;
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: can you explain connection between this code and OP's error? Don't assume and write answer.

Comment: @jaimin i am confused, is my algorithm for sort function wrong ??